# How to check the controls (display name and type) in the GroupBox by recursion and display on a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How to read controller properties, automatically added to a table assigned to a DataGridView?

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Name")
dt.Columns.Add("Type")
Dim n As Integer = Me.Controls.Count
For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
    dt.Rows.Add(Me.Controls(i).Name.ToString, Me.Controls(i).GetType.ToString)
Next

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

The above is the check for controls in the Form, it only displays **`Name`** and **`type`** of GroupBoxes, help me use recursive function to check the controls in GroupBox.

Below is my idea, but it was not working:

```
Public Sub V_gr(ByVal _Obj As Object)
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("Type")
    If (_Obj.Controls.count > 0) Then
        Dim i As Integer = _Obj.Controls.count - 1
        dt.Rows.Add(_Obj.Controls(i).Name.ToString, _Obj.Controls(i).GetType.ToString)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End If
End Sub
```

Use a temporary table assigned to DataGridView and display the control information checked on it with 2 columns **`Name`** and **`Type`**

Answer (score 0):

You can split the DataTable creation and the Controls enumeration in two different methods:

- The first method is the public one, which can be called just passing the Parent control from which to start the enumeration.
- This method just creates a DataTable, then calls the private method to fill it with the results of the enumeration
- The private method creates a new DataRow for each Control it finds and add it to the DataTable.

You could also modify the private method to return a List of objects that can be transformed to a DataTable after.

I've added a Column, named `"Parent"`, which references the Parent of the control. It may be useful to know which are the Parents of these Controls.

```
' Find all Controls in the current Form
DataGridView1.DataSource = ControlsListToDataTable(Me)
```

```
Private Function ControlsListToDataTable(parent As Control) As DataTable
    If (parent Is Nothing) OrElse (Not parent.HasChildren) Then Return Nothing
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("ParentControls")
    dt.Columns.AddRange({
        New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Name", .DataType = GetType(String)},
        New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Type", .DataType = GetType(String)},
        New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Parent", .DataType = GetType(String)}
    })
    GetAllControls(parent, dt)
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub GetAllControls(parent As Control, dt As DataTable)
    For Each ctl As Control In parent.Controls.OfType(Of Control)
        dt.Rows.Add({ctl.Name, ctl.GetType().FullName, ctl.Parent.Name})
        If ctl.HasChildren Then GetAllControls(ctl, dt)
    Next
End Sub
```

To find a Control in the DataTable, you can use the DataTable.DefaultView Sort and FindRows methods:

```
[DataTable].DefaultView.Sort = "Name"
Dim result = [DataTable].DefaultView.FindRows("TextBox1")
```

Or use a LINQ method:

```
Dim control = [DataTable].Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().
              FirstOrDefault(Function(dr) dr(0).ToString().Equals("TextBox1"))
```

Where `[DataTable]` can be the original DataTable returned by the public method or the `DataGridView.DataSource`:

```
 Dim dt = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
 Dim control = dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)(). (... etc ...)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work on my computer, I don't know why, I'm trying to understand what you say and fix it properly

Comment: I can't do that, can you use teamview and help me write a program when you're free?, Pleaseeeeeee!!!!!

Comment: Or can you make a video about when you write this program? then send it to my gmail: "nguyenduy97hy@gmail.com", I just started learning VB.net. Thank you very much.